# how to set the http headers when sending http request to a server so that the server thinks the requests are coming from firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, httphandler

how to set the http headers when sending http request to a server so that the server thinks the requests are coming from firefox

Comment: I think you meant to add a comment, not a moderator flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to alter the HTTP Header's User-Agent value, to something that looks like the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5
```

In C#/ASP.NET  (assuming this is follow-up on previous question)

```
using (WebClient myBrowser= new WebClient())
{
    myBrowser.Headers["User-Agent"] = some_string_like_the_one_above;

    // Download data.
    byte[] httpResp = myBrowser.DownloadData(some_url);

    // Here to exploit the data returned from the server
}
```

Comment: in your answer what is mybrowser variable

Comment: @Anirudha myBrowser is an instance of `WebClient` which is an object .NET supplies to create a virtual web browser which runs within one's program. I named it "myBrowser" because essentially it would be like a browser within the program, but it could be named anything else (? say webclt_one or whatever)